# Urn with black & white balls. Draw one ball then place it back. Repeat until 2 balls with different colors. Probability the last draw was white?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

So I'm having problems with this one. It says:
We draw with replacement two balls from an urn containing k black balls and l white balls where $k\ne l$ (with replacement the question means: draw one ball put it back in the urn, draw another ball put it back in the urn. So the experiment we are working here consists in drawing these 2 balls and comparing them, if they have the same color we start over with another experiment). This process is repeated until, for the first time, we draw two balls with different colors. Calculate the probability that the last ball you draw from this pair is white.

And the possible answers are: a) l/(k+l), b) k/(k+l), c) 1/2, d) 3/4, e) l(1-l)/(l(1-l)+k(1-k))

Should I use Bayes? I'm having problems modeling this problem.

Comment: If you meant with repetition, the question means that one ball is drawn at a time, then returned to the urn before the next draw.

Comment: yes you are right, a variation of this question was in the test I did some days ago and the teacher explained the same thing

Comment: Please edit your question and its title accordingly, then notify each person who has answered the question of the change.

Comment: Okay, just did that

Comment: If you drew the second ball without replacing the first ball, but then put both back, then the answer would be the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I'm bad at math and I have issues to understand the questions.

So indeed as N. F. Taussig said what the problem means with the reposition part is that you look at one ball then place it back in the urn, look at another ball place it back, do this until you draw 2 balls with different colors.

So the asnwer should be obvious but i need to prove it somehow, my teacher wants some logic in the answer so I tried to solve this using Bayes.

Let P(B) and P(W) be the probability of drawing a black and a white ball respectively and, for example, inside the experiment of drawing 2 balls, P(W1) is the probability of drawing a white ball in the first draw. Let A be the event where we draw 2 balls with different colors. So we want:

$$P(W2|A) = \frac{P(A|W2)*P(W2)}{P(A)}$$

Now $P(A) = P(W1)*P(B2) + P(B1)*P(W2)$

And $P(A|W2) = P(B1W2 + W1B2|W2) = P(B1)$

Which leave us with:
$$P(W2|A)=\frac{P(B1)*P(W2)}{P(B1)*P(W2)+P(W1)*P(B2)} = \frac12$$

Comment: So I talked to my teacher and the answer is 1/2, there are multiple ways to solve the problem and the way I did is one of them

Comment: Your answer of $1/2$ makes sense as the question is currently posed.

Answer (score 2):

You can disregard all instances where both balls have the same color. Just condition on the event that you have drawn two different balls. The answer then is obvious.

Comment: I edited the question to make it more clear